# How to map a SignalR hub to a path with an argument

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm building a backend with Asp.Net Core & SignalR. The data are not themself located on the Asp.Net Core, but must be requested to some other devices, that will send the data to the Asp.Net Core server, and then the server must give them back to the client through the web socket.

I would like to react to  the `OnConnectedAsync` to request my devices to send periodically some data to Asp.Net Core.

But this means that my hub must be able to know which data I need to be querying.

So I would like to have a Hub responding to the url `/api/data/{id}` and in my Hub, be able to know which ID has been requested.

```
app.MapHub<NotificationsHub>("/api/data/{id}");
```

The `id` identify a big group of data(that is requested and forwared as bulk), and multiple clients will request the same ID.

I can't find in the doc:

- If this is possible
- How should I specify the ID parameter?
- How do I retrieve this ID in the hub?

If anybody has some pointer, it would be helpful, thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass parameters as query string parameters. Pass the id from the connection url:

```
_hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl("/api/data?id=123")
    .Build();
```

Then read it inside hub:

```
public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    string id = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Query["id"];

    var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
    await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(connectionId, id);

    await base.OnConnectedAsync();
}

public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
{
    string id = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Query["id"];

    var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId
    await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(connectionId, id);
   
    await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
}
```

Send data:

```
_hubContext.Group("123").SomeMethod(dataBatch);
```

Map hub:

```
app.MapHub<NotificationsHub>("/api/data")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's not ideal, because this Hub will have to forward some data batches ONLY to the one with the ID 123, I was hopping to use the `_hubContext.Clients.All.SomeMethod(dataBatch)` and not have to manually create myself  some dictionary of clients for each data. But that's definitely some way I could "hack" the system if not possible otherwise.

Comment: You can add clients to groups based on the id parameter. Updated my answer.

Comment: That's really nice, I didn't know about Groups, thanks! Is there a way to know if a Group is empty? I need to stop the remote devices data if nothing is listening anymore. If not I guess I could manage my own list of Group member on the side, but that's a bit a shame.

Comment: Unfortunately checking if a group is empty is not supported out of the box. You have to implement your own solution to keep track of connection count per group. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66747507/check-if-a-group-contains-any-client

Comment: Fair enough, thank you for sharing your knowledge about Groups